# Starting Activities on different tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabs

In Activity A, I have 3 ImageView which call a function that starts Activity B. Activity B has 3 tabs. What's a way to correlate which tab Activity B starts with the ImageView? For example, if I push ImageView 2, I want the second tab to be shown when Activity B starts.

I know I can pass values between activities like so:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
 startActivity(intent)
```

But how do I correlate the ImageView from the XML to a specific tab I want to start in another activity?

Comment: I would hardcode the values for which tab on the click listener on each ImageView, so on the click listener of ImageView1 I put 1 in the intent extra

Comment: Perhaps set the id of the tab to display in the `android:tag` of the `ImageView` which you can retrieve in the `onClick(View v)` method via `v.getTag()` and pass this as an extra to `ActivityB`... seems you know the rest

Comment: @darnmason that was going to be my approach. I was checking if there were other ways to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a different code on each of your ImageView (ImageButon might be a better choice to consider BTW ;-) )

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityB.class);
 intent.putExtra("TABTODISPLAY", 1);// or 2, or 3
 startActivity(intent)
```

And then you can just do a switch of this number in ActivityB

I don't understand what's your problem and which step is giving you problem

If you are afraid of hardcoded numbers, there are many ways to achieve it..

1) You can use the tag property of the Image

2) You can use the onClick property of the ImageButton and switch the view name

3) You could use the onClickListener

etc.

Comment: Yes, but how will I know which tab is selected (1,2, or 3)? I can't hardcode the number

Comment: I added 3 ways to achieve it without using hardcoded numbers, but I still don't understand your requirement, there are too many ways to achieve what you want.. What's the problem with the tag that someone sanswered in comment? Whi con't you use the oncklick property? What are you expecting from the answer